# Property of 'java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>' type cannot be injected by 'List'

Tags: xml, spring, intellij-idea

I use intelliJ IDEA 16.1 version to practice Spring framework.

### Student Class

```
package com.tistory.johnmarc;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Student {

private String name;
private int studentId;
private String depart;
private ArrayList<String> lecture;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}

public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}

public String getDepart() {
    return depart;
}

public void setDepart(String depart) {
    this.depart = depart;
}

public ArrayList<String> getLecture() {
    return lecture;
}

public void setLecture(ArrayList<String> lecture) {
    this.lecture = lecture;
}
```

}

### StudentInfo Class

```
 package com.tistory.johnmarc;

/**
 * Created by JJH on 2016-07-11.
 */
public class StudentInfo {
    private Student student;

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }
public void getStudentInfo(){
    System.out.println(student.getName());
    System.out.println(student.getStudentId());
    System.out.println(student.getDepart());
    System.out.println(student.getLecture());
    System.out.println("=========================");
}
```

}

### spring configuration xml file

```
<bean id="student1" class="com.tistory.johnmarc.Student">
    <property name="name" value="장정현"/>
    <property name="studentId">
        <value>123</value>
    </property>
    <property name="depart">
        <value>software</value>
    </property>
    <property name="lecture" >
      <!-- Problem is there -->
        <list>
            <value>database</value>
            <value>OOAD</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I wrote the above code.

> Error Message is **Property of 'java.util.ArrayList' type cannot be injected by 'List'**

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the other way around - change your Student class to use List, not ArrayList.  The Student class doesn't need to know the List implementation.

So

```
private ArrayList<String> lecture;
```

should be

```
private List<String> lecture;
```

Similarly the getter & setter need to change to:

```
public List<String> getLecture() {
    return lecture;
}

public void setLecture(List<String> lecture) {
    this.lecture = lecture;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<bean id="student1" class="com.tistory.johnmarc.Student">
<property name="name" value="장정현"/>
<property name="studentId">
    <value>123</value>
</property>
<property name="depart">
    <value>software</value>
</property>
<property name="lecture" >
  <!-- Changes start -->
    <util:list list-class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <value>database</value>
        <value>OOAD</value>         
    </util:list>
  <!-- Changes end -->
</property>
```

Reference:
[Spring Lists proprties](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Spring/0120__Spring_List_Properties.htm)

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, but i have still problem. Error message is "Bean must be one of these types: java.lang.String or java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>..
Checks value types for Spring injections (properties & constructor arguments)"